# GlassFish 4 Rolling Upgrade Issue on Single Cluster

Tags: glassfish

I use GlassFish 4.1 single cluster with two instances on same node.

My steps for rolling upgrade:

1. deploy app with old version ClusterTest:1.0 
   (asadmin deploy --target=cluster1 --enabled=true --availabilityenabled=true --name=ClusterTest:1.0 ClusterTest.ear)
2. deploy new version app with disabled state ClusterTest:1.1 
   (asadmin deploy --target=cluster1 --enabled=false --availabilityenabled=true --name=ClusterTest:1.1 ClusterTest.ear)
3. enable app on 1st instance 
   (asadmin enable --target=instance1 ClusterTest:1.1)
4. On 1st instance new app is available, but on 2nd: 404 error (i expect available old version)

what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with rolling upgrades on GlassFish. Many of these problems have been fixed in the latest version of Payara Server. It may be that you aren't hitting any of these issues, but there is a very detailed discussion on the Payara GitHub repository:
https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/455

You may also want to look at this video which describes basic application versioning which may contain the information you need
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QVBsH6IjEA